# Numerically sorting arrays output

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort the output value that's returned by greatest to least.

Here's an example of the array:

```
array(
    'ACTION' => 'getsupportdepartments',
    'RESULT' => 'success',
    'TOTALRESULTS' => 2,
    'DEPARTMENTS' => array(
      'DEPARTMENT' => array(
        'ID' => 2,
        'NAME' => 'Sales',
        'AWAITINGREPLY' => 5,
        'OPENTICKETS' => 5
      ),
      'DEPARTMENT1' => array(
        'ID' => 1,
        'NAME' => 'Support',
        'AWAITINGREPLY' => 15,
        'OPENTICKETS' => 15
```

The code I'm using is:

```
if(!empty($_GET['sort'])) {
  $tmpArray = array();
  foreach($arr['WHMCSAPI']['DEPARTMENTS'] as $key => $value) {
    $tmpArray[$value['AWAITINGREPLY']] = $value;
  }
  $arr['WHMCSAPI']['DEPARTMENTS'] = $tmpArray;

  ($_GET['sort'] == 'desc') ? krsort($arr['WHMCSAPI']['DEPARTMENTS']) : ksort($arr['WHMCSAPI']['DEPARTMENTS']);
}


    ($_GET['sort'] == 'desc') ? krsort($arr['WHMCSAPI']['DEPARTMENTS']) : ksort($arr['WHMCSAPI']['DEPARTMENTS']);

  foreach($arr['WHMCSAPI']['DEPARTMENTS'] as $department) {
    echo $department['NAME'].' - '.$department['AWAITINGREPLY'].'<br />';
 }
  echo $exc;
```

However the order of the output from AWAITINGREPLY is not sorting.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is your desired output?

Comment: Currently, the output is:
Sales - 5
Support - 15

I would like to sort largest -> smallest

Support - 15
Sales - 5

Comment: So you want to sort the `['DEPARTMENTS']` array, order by `['AWAITINGREPLY']`?

Comment: Sorry, but this has likely been asked before, please first search the site. Also what has this to do with XML and API? I removed the tags because for the programming questions, this has nothing to do with those.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel, there's already a function called [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

[**online demo**](http://3v4l.org/CTYCT)

```
function sortDepts(array &$arr,$sort="desc")
{
    if($sort=="desc")
        usort($arr["DEPARTMENTS"],function($a,$b){
            return $b["AWAITINGREPLY"]-$a["AWAITINGREPLY"];
        });
    else
        usort($arr["DEPARTMENTS"],function($a,$b){
            return $a["AWAITINGREPLY"]-$b["AWAITINGREPLY"];
        });
    return $arr;
}
```

Note that anonymous function works in PHP>=5.3. If you need to support 5<=PHP<5.3, you'll need to declare the function first.

---

**Edit**:

For 5 < PHP < 5.3:

[online demo](http://3v4l.org/RALnX)

```
function asc($a,$b)
{
    return $a["AWAITINGREPLY"]-$b["AWAITINGREPLY"];
}
function desc($a,$b)
{
    return $b["AWAITINGREPLY"]-$a["AWAITINGREPLY"];
}
function sortDepts(array &$arr,$sort="desc")
{
    if($sort=="desc")
        usort($arr["DEPARTMENTS"],"desc");
    else
        usort($arr["DEPARTMENTS"],"asc");
    return $arr;
}
```

---

**Edit** #2:

In case you still need the key (`DEPARTMENT`,`DEPARTMENT1`,etc.), use [`uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead of `usort` (no other code change is required).

Comment: That doesn't work. Gives a blank output.

Comment: @cbcp Have you checked the online demo link? Which PHP version are you using?